# smartJqueryZoom plugin is not working for Android and iOS

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-plugins, pinchzoom

I am using smartJqueryZoom for Android and iOS, pinch zoom in it is working perfectly but I couldn't move the image once it is zoomed below is my code

HTML:

```
<div id="imagezoom" style = "margin-left:20%;margin-  top:12%;width:80%;height:80%">
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#imagezoom").append('<img id="zoom" src='+imgSrc+' alt="Zoom Images"  />').trigger("create");   
 $("#zoom").smartZoom();
```

I have also used touchMoveEnabled option in to true but still i have the same problem. Anyone please help me in fixing it. Or is there any good jquery pinch zoom?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: No error in console. Pinch and double tap works fine. Problem is only with dragging the image after it gets zoomed

Comment: Any chance to see an example of this issue?